# Order data by variable in R, what am I missing?

Tags: r, merge

I would like to order my data in a specific way. I introduced a variable "Index" in data.a and merged it with data.b. Afterwards the merged data is not in the right order, so I would like to order it again by the Index.
My merged Data looks like:

```
> str(aksamp.mer)
'data.frame':   11355 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ V    : Factor w/ 78 levels "","V1-18","V1-2",..: 3 23 49 49 17 41 10 10 40 39 ...
 $ J    : Factor w/ 7 levels "","J1","J2","J3",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 6 7 ...
 $ D    : Factor w/ 28 levels "","D1-1","D1-14",..: 3 23 7 7 22 22 18 18 8 9 ...
 $ Class: Factor w/ 1 level "IgG": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Count: int  63 59 1 58 52 50 49 7 43 41 ...
 $ Index: int  1051 10318 3218 3218 9887 9929 7503 7503 2438 3767 ...
```

I am trying to reorder the data.frame again by the column "Index":

```
> aksamp.mer2<-aksamp.mer[order(Index),]
```

which gives me the Error: "object 'Index' not found. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is complaining that there is no `Index` object in your environment. The right way to access it is to use `aksamp.mer$Index`. So you need to do:

```
aksamp.mer2 <-aksamp.mer[order(aksamp.mer$Index), ]
```