# How to run a unique in a column making sure it keeps the rows in ascending order

Tags: r

I have a observation month(ascending order) column as well an account number column. I want to run a unique/distinct in which I want unique account numbers but make sure that the rows R is taking is in ascending order as the observation month.

```
   Observation month A/C num

2010-09                 abc1
2010-10                 abc1
2010-11                  xyz
```

I want the unique to filter out only the first row as its in ascending order
I want to run a unique in my account number column so as I get the first entry of every account

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order data by variable in R, what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119852/order-data-by-variable-in-r-what-am-i-missing)

Comment: Maybe not. I want to run a unique/distinct in my accounts but I want the unique/distinct to give me the first entry in ascending order as I want every account's first entry.

Comment: Order first, then remove duplicates.

Comment: Ordering account numbers wont solve the question.

Comment: I know, but you could combine already answered questions if you split your problem accordingly (which is always a good approach when coding). Find the combined solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
df <- read.table(text = "Observation_month A_C_num
                 2010-09                 abc1
                 2010-10                 abc1
                 2010-11                  xyz", header = T)

df_correct_order <- df[order(df$Observation_month), ]
df_without_duplicates <- df_correct_order[!duplicated(df_correct_order$A_C_num), ]
df_without_duplicates

> df_without_duplicates
  Observation_month A_C_num
1           2010-09    abc1
3           2010-11     xyz
```

**Edit:**

If you prefer a `dplyr`-solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(Observation_month) %>% distinct(A_C_num, .keep_all = T)
```

Comment: Does that mean that duplicates always returns the first unique value, my observation month column in already in "order".

Comment: `duplicated` returns a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, indicating whether it is a duplicate or not. Hence, first occurency is `FALSE`, because not seen so far, all other same value are then `TRUE`. You want to Keep all non-duplicates, therefore `!duplicated()`. It always starts from top, unless you indicate it should go from bottom (`fromLast = TRUE`). Read `?duplicated` for more information.

Comment: library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(Observation_month) %>% distinct(A_C_num, .keep_all = T) This did not work. The distinct numbers were not in ascending order of observation months.

Comment: I get exact same output as `df_without_duplicates` from my example above. Isn't that order correct?

Comment: @alisha, please, update your question and show the expected result. From your question and the comments to both answers it is unclear what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has requested:

> I want the unique to filter out only the first row as its in ascending
>   order I want to run a unique in my account number column so as I get
>   the first entry of every account

This can be translated to an *aggregation* task

> Show the first, i.e., minimum, month of observation for each account number

#### `dplyr`

library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(A.C.num) %>% 
  summarise(Observation.month = min(Observation.month))

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
>   A.C.num Observation.month
>     <chr>             <chr>
> 1    abc1           2010-09
> 2     xyz           2010-11
> ```

#### `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, .(Observation.month = min(Observation.month)), by = A.C.num]
```

> ```
>    A.C.num Observation.month
> 1:    abc1           2010-09
> 2:     xyz           2010-11
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread(
  "   Observation.month A.C.num
2010-09                 abc1
2010-10                 abc1
2010-11                  xyz")
```

Comment: But here we not removing the duplicates or filtering out the unique.

Comment: @Alisha I do not understand your point. Isn't the result the same as Tino's? Is it possible that your sample dataset is not representative for your production data or that there are other requirements which you haven't disclosed?